# Check if a particular JSON Object is available or not in php

Tags: php, json

I have following JSON:

```
$p={
  "main1" : [
    {
      "child1" : valueA,
      "child2" : valueB,
      "child3" : valueC,
    },
    {
      "child1" : value1,
      "child3" : value3,
    },
  ],
  "main2" : "valueMain2"
}
```

The element `child2` has to be checked if it exists or not and then the value is taken. I am using json_decode:

```
$response = json_decode($p,true);
```

How do I check if an element exists or not in PHP? Do I have to make separate function or is there built-in functionality?

Comment: `isset($response['foo'])`?

Comment: or `array_key_exists("child2", $response);`

Comment: @lafor thanks that works perfectly fine. U can put it in the answer and i will accept it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The same way you'd check if a key of any array exists:

with `isset($array['key'])` or `array_key_exists('key',$array)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've been doing it.

```
$child2exists = count($response['main1']['child2']);

If ($child2exists == 1) 
{ 
    echo "EXISTS"; 
}
else
{ 
    echo "DOESNT EXIST"; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's either there or It's not, take a look at lafor's solution.

Comment: Yep. Lafors is a much better solution. I'm just saying how I did it. Although in my case, I also want it to return a number of how many entries it has IF it exists.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 / php 5.1.0 and later, use

```
$objJsn    = json_decode    ( $strJsnFromFile     );
$bolExists = property_exists( $objJsn, 'NodeName' );
```

from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php The array-related answer is wrong for php 7.4.9